# Wrong cardinality in UML class diagram

Tags: uml, multiplicity

My school teacher and me are arguing about how to write the correct cardinality to a relation between two classes:

```
    Customer ----places->---- Order
```

So the exercise tells me, that one customer has 0 - x orders and one order always belongs to one specific customer. So my idea was:

```
    Customer -1---places->---*- Order
```

My teachers solution:

```
    Customer -1..*---places->---*- Order
```

So, what do you think about it? I hope, I'm right :)

Comment: The teacher's solution has been edited to be very different from what it was in the original question. Has the original intent of the question been lost?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @alanb. If you found an answer to your
question, please consider [accepting
it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) (by clicking the
check-mark), and consider up-voting it (by clicking the up arrow).
Accepting an answer indicates to the wider community that you've
found a solution, gives yourself some reputation points, and gives
some reputation points to the person who answered your question.
If you did not find a satisfactory answer to your question, please
leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is correct. The 0..*, or just * for short, goes next to the Order class. The 1..1, or just 1 for short, goes next to the Customer class.

Are you sure your teacher specified UML?

Comment: In "normal" business I would agree. But without knowing the domain the answer is unknown. There might be a business where you have a single order that has many customers.

Comment: I think the question is where to put the multiplicities.

Comment: Yes. But the teacher can be right if you have a couple of people that place a single order. Unusual, but possible.

Comment: The OP told us, "one customer has 0 - x orders and one order always belongs to one specific customer".

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. Now I know that I'm on the right way :)

Comment: @alanb: You can show your appreciation by accepting and upvoting!

Answer (score 0):

*You* are right.

The 1:n relationship you're describing, states, that 1 Customer placed 0..n Orders. There may be Customers without an order, but if there is an order, there is one customer. One order must have 1 and only 1 customer. This totally makes sense to me.

The 1..n:? solution is broken in various respects. First, the Order side has no cardinality. But there is no default defined by specfication. Of course a diagram does not have to contain a cardinality, but a diagram is also just a view on the model. If you leave the cardinality out without mentioning it elsewhere it's *undefined*. Further, the 1..n cardinality states, that an Order has been placed by 1 or more Customers. Assuming the excercise relates to some real-world problem, this seems totally pointless to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now I know that I'm on the right way :)